# How to get Name by if from other table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to get name from other table by id of a table

Below is the "flavours" table contents

[image]

below is the "sales" table contents
[image]

In my Controller, I am using this function

```
 public function index() {
    if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group(array('admin'))) {
        redirect('home/permission');
    }
    $data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->getSettings();
    $data['all_sales'] = $this->sales_model->getAllSales();
    $data['flavour_name'] = $this->sales_model->getFlavourById($flavour_id);
    $this->load->view('home/dashboard', $data); // just the header file
    $this->load->view('sales/index', $data); 
    $this->load->view('home/footer'); // just the header file
}
```

In Model, i am using this function

```
function getFlavourById($flavour_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('sales');
    $this->db->join('flavours', 'flavour_id.id = name.id');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
}
```

In view i am using this

```
<?php foreach ($all_sales as $sale) { ?>
<tr class="">
    <td> <?php echo $sale->date; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $sale->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sale->flavour_name; ?></td> <!--- Need Flavour Name Here --->
    <td><?php echo $sale->mac_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sale->hdd_id; ?></td>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `flavours.id = sales.flavour_id` instead of `flavour_id.id = name.id`?

Comment: The`->flavour_name` would actually just be `$sale->name`, but since you are using the `*` (wildcard), you have both `sales.name` and `flavours.name`, so one will overwrite the other. You need to use an alias, ie. `flavours.name as flavour_name`.

Comment: Tried this, not working function getFlavourById($flavour_id) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('sales');
  $this->db->join('flavours', 'flavour_id.id = name.id');
  $query = $this->db->get(); 
    }

Comment: Change the `flavour_id.id = name.id` to `flavours.id = sales.flavour_id`

Comment: changed the code <code>public function index() {
  if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group(array('admin'))) {
            redirect('home/permission');
        }
        $data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->getSettings();
        $data['all_sales'] = $this->sales_model->getAllSales();
  $data['flavour_name'] = $this->sales_model->getFlavourById();
        $this->load->view('home/dashboard', $data); // just the header file
        $this->load->view('sales/index', $data); 
        $this->load->view('home/footer'); // just the header file
    } </code>

Comment: after changing , getting error Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$flavour_name